Record two specific areas + background sound AND input audio (with ffmpeg)
So how do I record my screen with background sound AND input audio with ffmpeg? And could you also record two areas on the screen at once (so that, for example, another area is displayed at the bottom left during recording)?
-RD

I have a solid starting point.The chosen input will display in the bottom left corner, pip style, during a desktop capture.
Uses mpv & curl for URL's & ffmpeg -re for a file input (mkfifo & mpv) to a splash style window, stripped decorations, and "always on top".
Here's what I've concocted:
#!/bin/bash

move_mpv_window() {
  mpv_window=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid "$pidmpv")
  if [ -n "$mpv_window" ]; then
    xdotool windowmove "$mpv_window" 28 528 2>/dev/null
  else
    echo "Failed to find the mpv window."
    return 1
  fi
}

pip_client() {
  sleep 5
  echo -e "\npip client: (id=$pipe_id) $name"

  mpv --really-quiet=yes --ytdl-format=18 --geometry=420x220 --force-window-position=yes --taskbar-progress=no \
      --cursor-autohide=always --ontop=yes --window-dragging=no --auto-window-resize=no --demuxer-mkv-probe-video-duration=yes \
      --title-bar=no --border=no --osc=no "$client_input" & pidmpv=$!
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error occurred while starting mpv."
    return 1
  fi

  sleep 5
  echo "  retrieving window id..."
  sleep 5
  echo "  moving window..."
  move_mpv_window
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "  window positioning failed."
    return 1
  else
    echo "  playback successful."
  fi

  ffmpeg -hide_banner -f pulse -i default -f x11grab -i "$DISPLAY" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -preset ultrafast -crf 20 "desk_rec_${time_stamp}.mkv"
}

pipe_output() {
  pipe_id=$(tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9_-' < /dev/urandom | fold -w 6 | head -n 1)
  mkfifo "$pipe_id"

  pip_client &

  echo -e "\npicture-in-picture server:\n (id=$pipe_id) $name\n  streaming..."

  ffmpeg -re -movflags +frag_keyframe -y -i "$input" -c copy -f "$format" -s 420x220 -preset ultrafast "$pipe_id" 2>/dev/null

  rm "$pipe_id"
}

input="$1"
time_stamp=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%p")
name=$(basename "$input" | sed 's/\..*//')
format=$(echo "$input" | awk -F '/' '{split($3, ext, "."); print ext[2]}')

if curl --head --silent --fail "$input" > /dev/null; then
  client_input="$input"
  pip_client
fi

extension="${input##*.}"
if [[ "$extension" =~ ^(mp4|m4v|mkv|webm|avi)$ ]]; then
  client_input="./$pipe_id"
  format="mp4"
  pipe_output
fi

exit 0

Save as: capture_pip.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x capture_pip.sh
Usage: ./capture_pip.sh URL or ./capture_pip.sh /path/to/file.mkv
Here's an example video of the script.
Pulse with ALSA:
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse
Internal microphone:
-f oss -i /dev/dsp1
Capturing two area's and audio sources will depend mostly on the system's ability.  It's feasible.  As long as you have a fairly fast machine.
Make sure to check audio mixer, or alsamixer. The input device must be set to "monitor".

You can use the following command with ffmpeg to record both audio and video:
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -i :0.0+0,0 -f alsa -i pulse -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac output.mp4

With a resolution of 1920 x 1080 pixels and a frame rate of 30 frames per second, this command will record the screen. It will record system audio as well. The recording will be stored in the current directory with the filename output.mp4.
